# How to assign F9 key to play/pause iTunes?

Tags: itunes, keyboard

I change my front panel on my MacBook late 2007. I'm on mountain Lion.

I already attached Next and Previous (song) button to F10 and F8. But can't F9 button force to work. I think I don't know the action word for play/pause command. I tried 'Play', 'Pause', 'Play/Pause', 'Play or Pause', etc.

How can I attach Play/Pause iTunes button to any F8-F10 button?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can’t set a shortcut for “Play” in iTunes. It remains the spacebar key and I have used an alternate method with third party software to get F9 to be the shortcut for play. Reply if you would accept a third party solution.

Comment: @duci9y oh, i didn't know about that is impossible for "Play":( . Thanks for you reply, i don't need a third party solution.

Comment: But the third party solution is really inconspicuous and free. It remaps the F9 key on your keyboard to a “play” key like on a real Apple keyboard.